# What can i do if chrome keep crash on large data render and faster the server response

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql-workbench

I have a webpage that create table with sql data

Problem 1: fetching process took too long
the whole process below took 1.30s to 1.50s (inspect from devTools), wait for server to response take around 1s and content download take around 325ms, each request contain 40000-60000 rows from sql.

```
1. button call js function
2. js fetch php
3. php request sql
4. sql receive and send back the request
5. php echo result wrap with html table tag and send back to js
6. js get the response and render it to html
```

Problem 2: chrome crash while render new content
after sucess render to page as a table with display first row only and the rest `display:none`
,when click on first column of the first row, it set the rest row to `display:""`, then google chrome crash with error message `out of memory`

How do i solve those problem , Thanks in advance

IDE: vscode
SQL: mysql workbench, Mysql8.0
localhost with xampp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hey you question is very general,you need to check your indexing in mysql,you need to check your php code and you can use design pattern to have clean code and scability also you can use comporess technology like php-zip to compress your response
at the front end you need to use cache technology and you need to check you code and try to minify
also i sugest you to paginate response data

because you didn't show your code exactly and you question in general i try to help you to find and solve problem hope is helpful for you

also for mor information you can see links below

- [How to make SQL queries faster and more efficient](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjfk5CB87v5AhWE_qQKHbF3AM0QFnoECBAQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freelancer.com%2Farticles%2Fweb-development%2Fhow-to-make-your-sql-queries-faster&usg=AOvVaw2dpTSjS4qp2p0cxnBUCQ7N)
- [gzcompress - Manual](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjVioCs87v5AhU_YPEDHe5QAsoQFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.gzcompress.php&usg=AOvVaw3JIiU4zw9sQOeZHIwLAk9t)
- [Cache - Web APIs | MDN](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjqg8_X87v5AhU5gv0HHVhXDhIQFnoECBAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FCache&usg=AOvVaw3wr780LheViUEnKzrZ0Jfj)

Comment: If i show my code here , it will be very long